# Allow to add webpart inside my webpart / Nested webparts

Tags: web-part

my problem is the following:

I have developed a web part using the SharePoint Framework (with HTML, CSS, JS / React) which basically is a "Read more" / Collapsible section.

```
<Read more button>
------------------------------------------
<Section that opens when clicking on the Read more button>
(=> in this section I want the "Add webpart" button)
```

You click on the read more button, and the section expands / shows up.
In this section, I want to give the possibility to show this "Add webpart" button so that basically any webpart could be collapsed in this section. Basically this menu:

[image]

I couldn't find any possibility to do that but I can't believe that this is not implementable.

Are there any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Is the collapsible area always in the same spot in the site? If so, it may be easier to target that area, which then wraps a web part zone, and make that collapsible via CSS or script instead of creating a collapsible web part and trying to nest web parts within it. You can't have parent web parts.